# Build Qt4 project with Serialport support using CMake

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm trying to build Qt4 (version 4.8.6) project with Serialport support using CMake (version 2.8.12). Here is the line that adds Qt4 support from my CMake:

```
find_package (Qt4 COMPONENTS QTCore QTGui REQUIRED)
include("${QT_USE_FILE}")
add_executable(myapp ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myapp ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

and getting the following error:

```
fatal error: QSerialPort: No such file or directory #include <QSerialPort>
```

I understand that FindQt4.cmake module doesn't have Serialport since it was introduced in Qt5 so i built Serialport library from sources. So the question is how to include the Qt library that is absent in FindQt4.cmake module to build the project via CMake.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I want to understand if it is possible to build the app mentioned above using CMake or i should only use qmake.

Comment: Why do you want to mix Qt4 with a part of Qt5 (Serialport)? Why not just using Qt5? Migration from 4.8.6 would be far easier. That's what seems to be the XY problem. That's not about CMake vs qmake

Comment: I see what you mean but the use of Qt is limited to Qt4 and i wanted to know if it is possible to build the app via CMake. If not i will use qmake. That's why i asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

The serial port module's code should be a part of your project. Since the project depends on Qt 4, lacking that module, you must bring the code with you. It just a couple of files, adding them to your project is trivial.